# Is it a good practice to block all inbound traffic on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, firewall

Windows firewall has many inbound rules which allow access to many ports and services. Should this be a security concern? If a Windows device is not used as a server, is it a good practice to disable all the inbound rules?

Note: My question is whether it is a *good practice* to disable these rules, not *how* to disable them.

Comment: On Windows you can always select between "public" and "private" network. The firewall settings depend on what you select. It could be important to select "public" when you are in a public network. See this screenshot https://www.top-password.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/network-location-type.png

Comment: I think blocking all inboud traffic is not good practice. Because that would mean you do not trust Windows default firewall settings.

Comment: It may be that you are missing the stateful nature of the firewall. unsolicited traffic to a port is generally blocked regardless of the rules you are seeing. the rules are for what happens after stateful filtering, which is determined by your firewall profile for that network.

Answer (score 2):

> If a Windows device is not used as a server, is it a good practice to disallow all the ports?

**No.**  Normal web communication involves two way traffic.  HTTPS Downloads certainly involve incoming data.  File transfer involves two way transfer. Email involves two way transfer.

I could go on, of course, but the default Windows Firewall settings are well tested and do not create problems.

All users must always be vigilant and not receive (download) phishing emails and not click on links designed to hijack your machine.

Make sure you keep Windows  AND  Windows Defender up to date and that Windows Defender is always active.

Comment: HTTPS downloads do not require the client to open any ports. A random port of the client establish a connection with port 443 of the server, and they communicate using that connection (client's incoming firewall rules do not intervene since the connection is requested by the client). Also note that on Linux, all ports except 22 (ssh) are blocked by default. Linux devices can still browse the web and email.

Answer (score 0):

Attack surface is a security concern, and defaults should be evaluated.

Microsoft has a [constellation of pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security) for how to thoughtfully approach this.

A blanket disable will break some software.